# Convert Raw Vector back to Excel R

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am working with an Excel file saved in S3. I am trying to access it using R. To get the file I am using `fl <- get_object(paste(file_path,file_name),bucket = bucket)`. This works fine and returns the file in raw vector format. The problem I am having is that any function I have found to read an Excel file requires an actual file (ie path), not a raw vector.

Is there a way to read a raw vector (of an Excel file) into a data frame? Or, convert the raw vector back to an Excel file so I can reference that file in `read_excel()` or the like?

The python code below does what I need, but for reasons far beyond my control, I must do this in R.

```
fl = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key= file_path + file_name)
df = pd.read_excel(fl['Body'])
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example? That would be helpful to provide a solution.